# I have the app and my database designer quit (need terminology help)

Tags: javascript, c#, database-design

so me and a friend started a venture for an app as I'm sure many other friends did as well.  My job was to develop the app and his was to develop the web page and database.

Brief description:  The app is the end product and relies on information uploaded by users.  This information is uploaded to the database through the web page and the app.  The app in turn pulls information from this database and performs its functions with it.

Well, now the app is done and the site is only partially developed.  He seems to have dropped off the face of the planet and I don't want to abandon the project.

My questions:
1) The queries to the database were being made using php searches.  To start off, is that the right terminology?
2) I've stumbled across a ton of different hosting sites and software today.  What site/software allows you to use server side code to error check data and store it? (I've seen a lot about wordpress but still don't grasp what I really need)
3) Most web pages seem to use java to check the form entries.  However, Java seems to be an overarching group for a bunch of sub categories.  What version of Java should I start learning to work with forms on web pages?

I'm a novice on this side of the fence, but what I need doesn't seem overly complicated in my mind so I'm pretty sure with a little direction I can start researching and learning how to get this done. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: java and javascript are as closely related  as pain is to painter. A back end using php would very unlikely have any java involved.

Comment: You can try using Firebase which is much easier to handle.